# Android HTTP exception

Tags: java, android

I am using following code to log in to Dropbox, but it throws an exception.

Code:

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://www.dropbox.com/login");

    // set values you'd like to send
    List pairs = new ArrayList();
    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login_email", "my email id"));
    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login_password", "******"));
    /*'login_email' and 'login_password' i found html form fields name by viewing the page source of https://www.dropbox.com/login */

    try {
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
        // set ResponseHandler to handle String responses
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String response = client.execute(post, responseHandler);
        Log.v("HttpPost", "Response: " + response);
        if (response.contains("SUCCESS")){
            // express your joy here!
        } else {
            // pop a sad Toast message here...
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("", String.valueOf(e));
    }
}
```

Logcat

```
         11-14 23:17:35.734: E/Trace(900): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
         11-14 23:17:38.793: D/dalvikvm(900): GC_CONCURRENT freed 251K, 4% free 8194K/8519K, paused 126ms+9ms, total 234ms
         11-14 23:17:39.895: E/(900): org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Forbidden
         11-14 23:17:40.364: I/Choreographer(900): Skipped 75 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
         11-14 23:17:40.394: D/gralloc_goldfish(900): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
         11-14 23:17:40.784: I/Choreographer(900): Skipped 62 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
         11-14 23:17:43.614: W/chromium(900): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/backend_impl.cc:1829: [1114/231743:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1829)] Destroying invalid entry.
```

Comment: please post the full logcat stack trace...

Comment: You may want to change your password, too, if those are real credentials in the code.

Comment: And your email address.  The spiders will come to eat you!  Shouldn't this be a GET, not a POST?

Comment: @ Praful Bhatnaga i have edited the code please check

Comment: @acj - considering the response was "Forbidden" (presumably error code 403), that's probably not the correct password :)

Comment: @TedHopp Not taking any chances. Dropbox does some extra verification for non-browser authentication IIRC, so it may be raising an error that's unrelated to the credentials.

Comment: FYI, Dropbox has a REST API that will provide a much cleaner interaction between them and your app than trying to mimic browser form behavior: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api

Answer (score 3):

```
I/Choreographer(900): Skipped 75 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

It is always suggested to do Network activity on separate thread instead of main thread by using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Here is android tutorial on [Connecting to the Network](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html)

Answer (score 2):

i tried your request from rest plug in and got the following response from server:

Status
403 Forbidden

```
<html>
<head><title>Dropbox - 403</title>
<link href="https://www.dropbox.com/static/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/images/favicon.ico"/>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#fff">
<br/><br/>
<div align="center">
<table><tr><td width="600px">
<center><img id="errorimage" src="/static/images/lockbox.png"/></center>
<div id="errorbox">
<h1>Error (403)</h1>It seems you tried to do something we can't verify.  Did you log into a different Dropbox account in a different window?  Try clicking <a href="#" onclick="history.go(-1); return false;">here</a> to go back to the page you came from, or just go <a href="/home">home</a>.
</div>
</td></tr></table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

where is the dropbox API definitions that you are using for login?

you should try their rest API for the integration defined at following link:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api

EDIT1: dropbx also have sdk for mobile platform that you can use. check [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/sdk) for SDK's.

EDIT2: just checked the login page of dropbox. Following is the relevant HTML from login form:

```
<form action="https://www.dropbox.com/login" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="t" value="Hch4dxqGBwUN024pIuQbsxUQ" /><div class="sick-input small"><label for="login_email_elm">Email</label><input type="text" id="login_email_elm" name="login_email" tabindex="1" /></div><div class="sick-input small"><label for="login_password_elm">Password</label><input type="password" id="login_password_elm" name="login_password" tabindex="2" /></div><p style="margin-bottom: 0.5em; line-height: 28px;"><input style="vertical-align: middle; margin-left: 0;" name="remember_me" class="no-border" type="checkbox" id="remember_me" tabindex="3" /><label style="vertical-align: middle; cursor: pointer; " for="remember_me">Remember me</label><input tabindex="4" type="submit" class="freshbutton-blue" value="Sign in" id="toplogin-submit" /><input type="hidden" name="cont" value="https://www.dropbox.com/" /></p><p class="create-account"><a href="/register" id="login-create-an-account">Create an account</a></p></form>
```

it has two hidden parameter `t` with auto-generated value which i guess is used by the Dropbox for stoping people to use it the why you are using. Another one is a `cont` whoch has hardcorded value `https://www.dropbox.com/`

Any way I tried the request with these two parameter and was able to get the success response. Following is the detail of my request and response using the rest plug in for chrome:

Request URI: `https://www.dropbox.com/login`

Request content type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Request post data:

> login_email=bscscomsats@gmail.com&login_password=yourpassword&t=Hch4dxqGBwUN024pIuQbsxUQ&cont=https://www.dropbox.com/

Reponse: `To:https://www.dropbox.com/ with status: 302`

Response Header:

```
Server: nginx/1.2.3 
Date: Wed, 14 Nov 2012 18:29:36 GMT 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 
Transfer-Encoding: chunked 
Connection: keep-alive
set-cookie: lid=AACt_twZtlN8Tz7TDINxpJFUFvG44oy3YAKZ7ht0umJMxA; Domain=www.dropbox.com; Path=/; secure; httponly
set-cookie: forumjar=eyJ2ZXJpZmllZCI6IDAsICJ1aWQiOiAxMjEwMjcwODYsICJleHBpcmVzIjogMTM1MzAwNDE3NiwgInBhaWQiOiAwLCAibG5hbWUiOiAiQ2xvdWRldHMiLCAiZm5hbWUiOiAiUG9ja2V0IiwgImRpc3BsYXlfbmFtZSI6ICJQb2NrZXQgQ2xvdWRldHMiLCAiZW1haWwiOiAiYnNjc2NvbXNhdHNAZ21haWwuY29tIn0%3D; Domain=dropbox.com; Path=/; httponly
set-cookie: blid=AACUWWo4_oPc00S7cf-xtgZ8dkkXXIkiyP8uQazNqQXjXw; Domain=dropbox.com; Path=/; secure; httponly
set-cookie: oscar=; Domain=www.dropbox.com; expires=Wed, 14-Nov-2012 18:29:36 GMT; Path=/; httponly
set-cookie: jar=W3sidWlkIjogMTIxMDI3MDg2LCAiaCI6ICJBQUNiSHJrUElzeWtiYUltak5MZWVnWE52OGYtRmxtZXJubXVXc0xnbnRlallRIiwgImV4cGlyZXMiOiAxMzUzMDA0MTc2LCAibnMiOiAxOTU2NzYxNjcsICJyZW1lbWJlciI6IGZhbHNlfV0%3D; Domain=www.dropbox.com; Path=/; secure; httponly
set-cookie: checkpoint=; Domain=www.dropbox.com; expires=Wed, 14-Nov-2012 18:29:36 GMT; Max-Age=0; Path=/; httponly
set-cookie: t=vmmVuSRbO6xqVJTJ9meSJVkf; Domain=dropbox.com; expires=Fri, 14-Dec-2012 18:29:36 GMT; Path=/; secure; httponly
set-cookie: grouch=; Domain=www.dropbox.com; expires=Wed, 14-Nov-2012 18:29:36 GMT; Path=/; httponly
set-cookie: bjar=W3sic2Vzc19pZCI6IDY3MDc1MTI0NDU3NDk5NzkwMTQ3OTg2NzExOTY1Njc4MDQ1NTA1LCAiZXhwaXJlcyI6IDEzNTMwMDQxNzYsICJ1aWQiOiAxMjEwMjcwODZ9XQ%3D%3D; Domain=dropbox.com; Path=/; secure; httponly
set-cookie: forumlid=NTM1NmJmYTU0NzQ2ZjgzMTNhZDI0YWE5ZjljZjZjNzViY2IxMzliYw%3D%3D; Domain=dropbox.com; Path=/; httponly
strict-transport-security: max-age=2592000; includeSubDomains
location: https://www.dropbox.com/
pragma: no-cache
cache-control: no-cache
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
```

Redirection response:

```
Status
200 OK
```

Response header:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Charset: UTF-8,*;q=0.5
Cookie: gvc=NjcwNzUxMjQ0NTc0OTk3OTAxNDc5ODY3MTE5NjU2NzgwNDU1MDU%3D; t=Hch4dxqGBwUN024pIuQbsxUQ; __utma=74146836.1139928866.1352917086.1352917086.1352917086.1; __utmb=74146836.4.10.1352917086; __utmc=74146836; __utmz=74146836.1352917086.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided)
```

the response data can be found at this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/BkTRP7Rw) link.

So since the vale of `t` parameter in login form is auto generated by Dropbox and which i am sure expire after few minutes so I would suggest not to use this approach for login..

Comment: The SDK for android didn't login the user in background progmatically,  want that login to hide from user.